# jquery datepicker doesn't load

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've searched over many threads with this problem, but none was helpful for my case.

The datepicker does not want to load on my page.
Here's the resource list:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jscripts/demos.css" />
```

And here's the jquery code right after:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){           
            $("#d1, #d2").datepicker(); 
    });
    </script>
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks.

UPDATE:
SORRY, I forgot to add the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="d1" name="d1" size="15" style="text-align:right;" />
```

[...]

```
<input type="text" id="d2" name="d2" size="15" style="text-align:right;" />
```

Tried to output to console : `console.log($("#d1, #d2"));` and the selector is OK, it gave me the right inputs.
ERROR: I get the following error (got via FireBug):
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' index.php:17
(anonymous function) index.php:17
fire jquery-latest.js:1017
self.fireWith jquery-latest.js:1127
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-latest.js:416
DOMContentLoaded

UPDATE: I've just uploaded the whole page code here: [jsfiddle.net/v69eH](http://jsfiddle.net/v69eH)

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Can you post any error you're getting in the console? Also, ensure your custom script is at the very end, after you've included all the files.

Comment: It works for me. Do you have your inputs with `id="d1"` and `id="d2"`.

Comment: just updated post with error code and HTML code

Comment: It works for me. So i guess it is a problem with the way your scripts are loaded like @badZoke mentioned in their comment.

Comment: Sounds like jQuery UI isn't loaded before the $(document).ready function is being run. Is the script appearing in your chosen developer tools? Could try placing console.log(jQuery.ui); before the datepicker line to see if this is the case.

Comment: I've just uploaded the whole page code here: http://jsfiddle.net/v69eH/

Comment: @pwdst : you're right, the ui is not loaded, it gives undefined. I dont know what should I do

Comment: have you tried downloading the code and load it locally? I had a similar issue when the browser was receiving the JS from CDN after document ready

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro I have tried to download the ui and load it locally, and the same happened. I'm going to download every single script and load it so. I'll b back with an update on that. Thanks

Comment: the same happened even if loaded from local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As you can see I have another jQuery load in the code, right before the content part. That has overwriten the first loaded jQuery and of course the document.load event as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in the body of your page:

```
<input id='d1' type='text' /><br/>
<input id='d2' type='text' />
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw5rD/